VBA Verification if the M365 account is properly logged in
The file is shared via a link on OneDrive, the user opens it in the desktop application and makes changes (the opening and changes are executed by a VBA macro). If the user is not logged into M365 or is logged in but encounters an error such as: "Unfortunately, your account is currently unavailable. To resolve this issue, please log in again." (we occasionally see this error "randomly" on various computers, although others on the same license work), the link will open in the browser, and in that case, I won't be able to make any changes to it. The can't see that such a file exists or what is being saved in it. I could do this with a local file on the server, but I want the user to be able to make changes to it, and for supervisors to see those changes in real time, which a local file won't provide (unless that's possible?).
I tried to force it to open in Excel by changing the default setting for opening links in the desktop application.
Creating a shortcut and saving the link there to open it in Excel also doesn't work. Forcing it to open via PowerShell doesn't work either.
All these actions result in Excel opening, but then the file opens in the browser (unless the user is properly logged in). As for login verification, I was only able to find the login details in files or registry keys, but no trace of any potential error.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
